# GROUP_CONCAT not working with left join

Tags: mysql, left-join, group-concat

This query is showing error : 
 #1054 - Unknown column 'sp.spot_id' in 'on clause'

Query :

```
SELECT product.*,sp.sp_name FROM `product` 
     left join spot_selling on product.product_id=spot_selling.product_id 
      AND spot_selling.end_time >= now() 
      AND spot_selling.start_time <= now() 
      AND spot_selling.status='1' 
    left join(select GROUP_CONCAT(s.name SEPARATOR ',') as sp_name 
from spot s group by s.spot_id) sp on sp.spot_id=spot_selling.spot_id 
WHERE product.user_id='26' AND product.status!='6'
```

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need `spot_id` in the subquery, so there is something to join on:

```
SELECT product.*, sp.sp_name
FROM `product` left join
      spot_selling
      on product.product_id=spot_selling.product_id AND
         spot_selling.end_time >= now() AND
         spot_selling.start_time <= now() AND
         spot_selling.status = '1' left join
      (select spot_id, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name SEPARATOR ',') as sp_name 
--------------^
       from spot s
       group by s.spot_id
      ) sp
      on sp.spot_id = spot_selling.spot_id 
WHERE product.user_id = '26' AND product.status <> '6'
```